# Provide a way to use counters in Hive through UDF

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is there a way to add user defined counters in Hive for UDF/UDAF/UDTF ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, 
https://issues-test.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3628

Example:

```
Usage:

public class UDAFEvaluator extends GenericUDAFEvaluator{

@Override
public void iterate(final AggregationBuffer agg, final Object[] parameters) throws HiveException
{        MapredContext.get().getReporter().getCounter(...).increment(1);    }
}
```